# Adding Connected Clients To A List - C

Tags: c, linux, windows, sockets, winsock

I have created a client and server, both written in C, and am now looking at editing the server to handle multiple clients. The question I have is: Is there any way I can add the incoming connections/connected clients to a list that could be printed to the terminal? For example:

Connected Clients:

[1] Client 1

[2] Client 2

I am using raw sockets for this. The server runs on Linux using raw sockets and the client runs on windows using WinSock2 and so far seems to run well.

Comment: Yes there is a way. Have a list and add to it. Then print it. What is the actual question?

Comment: Have a look at `man QUEUE`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here goes the answer: yes, you actualy can do this, just follow the steps:

1. Create socket for server
2. Set it to NONBLOCKING mode with following code:

   fcntl(sock, F_SETFL, O_NONBLOCK);
3. Bind it and set listening for it
4. Accept socket (check for -1 and errno (if -1 and errno set to EWOULDBLOCK then there is no clients that want to connect to your server))
5. Set them to NONBLOCKING mode.
6. Store sockaddr* (sockaddr_in or sockaddr_in6) and client socket
7. Repeat steps 4 - 6
8. Now multiple clients connected to your server.
9. Check when write or read from clients for -1 and errno (for disconect detection)

And remember! ALWAYS CHECK THE RETURN VALUES. Otherwise you may be in trouble. Also check the [IP man pages](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/ip.7.html) for linux networking.

Comment: Thanks that helped a lot!